# Is it rightly understood that any termination without just cause are unjust practices

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales, civil-law, consumer-protection, terms-of-service

Let's assume a Telco has terminated a consumer's lines without just cause. The disconnection is due to their failure of rectifying a billing issue. They didn't provide any customer support during the period of disconnection. More context is in an earlier post [What's the consumer's rights in a Telco billing dispute?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86861/whats-the-consumers-rights-in-a-telco-billing-dispute)

If to proceed to a small claims court or relevant authorities, is there a need to provide documents or evidence to prove that the disconnections have adverse impact on the consumer or is it rightly understood that any terminations without just cause are unjust practices?

Comment: Welcome to this board. Contract law varies from country to country, so you would need to specify the jurisdiction. And even then, there would be particulars to every case which are difficult to answer on this board. For legal advice on a specific case, you need a lawyer, not some people answering on the net in their spare time.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with a contract that allows one or both parties to terminate without cause.  So at the least, a court would need to see the contract and confirm that it *doesn't* allow at-will termination.  Telecom is usually highly regulated, though, so it's not a matter of pure contract law.

Comment: As a trivial example, if you subscribe to a magazine, then decide to cancel your subscription, you don't have to have "just cause".  You can terminate the subscription for any reason, including a mistaken reason, a stupid reason, or no reason at all.  There's nothing unjust about that.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge my question has not considered the scenarios you have quoted. That makes sense